# Winter Wheat & Wildfires

Tags: lightning, agriculture

TL;DR: How susceptible is winter wheat to wildfire, in the environment that winter wheat is used?

The scenario:

Shallow water table, a steppe environment, deep-root winter wheat and a HIGH occurrence of lightning strikes.

Would wildfires be a realistic risk? Wouldn't the wheat be too hydrated to be set alight?