# Is there an Existing Model of Computing Rice Sufficiency?

Tags: agriculture

I've been researching agricultural systems out of my curiosity.
And so I've been thinking how do the Officials know that the Rice Produce or **YIELD**, will be **satisfiable** to a certain country, or small village.

My question is: "Is there an **existing model** for ***computing Sufficiency*** for a place **based on Yield of rice**, and the **Demand of the Population?**"

Most likely I aim for a Percentage Output, but anyway I can alter.

If there's none can you enlighten me of some Key terms, That can lead me into building one myself. Can be Studies, articles or Algorithms, and Approaches.

Comment: Could you specific, for which type of model your are looking? I would expected that there is just a constant rice consumption per person assumed (and then multiplied by the number of inhabitants).

Comment: This is an agriculture question, not earth science.

Comment: That's what my question is sir, model/format I hardly can't find something close to what I specify(bold words)

Comment: As, currently, there is no agriculture stack exchange, and there is an "agriculture" tag in stack exchange, the question seems to be on topic. When an agriculture stack is proposed, then this and other questions like https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/will-global-warming-lead-to-agriculture-in-the-arctic and https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12017/winter-wheat-wildfires can migrate there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rice production and yield, like any other agricultural crop depends on a number of factors. These include, but not limited to:

- The variety of rice being grown
- The fertility of the soil, and this can and does vary between regions
  in countries
- The availability of water for the variety of rice
- Loss due to pests or natural events (ie weather)

When new varieties of rice are developed, test plots are planted in various locations and the yield per area of land, typical tonnes per hectare, are ascertained. Once this has been done for a number of test plots and for a number of growing seasons, average numbers of tonnes per hectare can then be applied to larger/national plantings.

Combine this with data regarding the number of people that need to be fed and the determined average of the amount of rice each person needs it is possible to determine the sufficiency of a rice production.

Comment: You totally got the whole picture! yes I already have conceptualized a working format from Rice Yields (Expected - Actual = Gap) Where Actual is a variable already. And I also have a dummy information of population and their consumption, So that will be the KEYWORD how would I determine the sufficiency from these data I have